# ie8 gives error "object does not support this method or property" on uploading a second image

Tags: jquery, flash, internet-explorer-8, image-compression

I'm trying to implement shift8creative's agile uploader.  All works well in proper browsers, but ie is causing problems.

the page is here:https://www.postadigi.com/pages/upload-order

the line the js error is highlighting is here:

```
document.getElementById('agileUploaderSWF').sendForm();
```

Iv'e tried putting it in a onclick, a jquery click function.  Same error.

NB, it compresses & uploads a first image fine, but then when a second image is selected and upload clicked, it fails.

Comment: sorry,  by "ie" i mean ie8.  we arn't supporting older browsers for the compressor up-loader widget.

Comment: Sorry again. On rereading that it makes no sense: clicking the upload button the second time round throws the error:object does not support this method or property and therefore the form is not submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, fixed it.

Internet explorer was caching the swf data as detailed here:

http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashcache/index.html

So thanks to a tip from Richard Grove on the plugins comments, i fixed it with a bit of trickery:

flashSrc: '/js/uploader/agile-uploader.swf?' + Math.random(),

Which seems to have convinced ie to not cache it.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('agileUploaderSWF').sendForm();
```

Comment: yes, sorry.  typo on my part in the question.  Its got the full stop in the code. thanks for looking for me though.